# Android read text file and store into variable based on first word

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I am doing a reading text file practice where I read and store the data into a string array object. One ArrayList data should have photo, title, website, and date. The text file looks like this:

```
photo:android_pie
title:Android Pie: Everything you need to know about Android 9
website:https://www.androidcentral.com/pie
date:20-08-2018
photo:oppo
title:OPPO Find X display
website:https://www.androidpit.com/oppo-find-x-display-review
date:25-08-2018
photo:android_pie2
title:Android 9 Pie: What Are App Actions & How To Use Them
website:https://www.androidheadlines.com/2018/08/android-9-pie-what-are-app- 
actions-how-to-use-them.html
date:16-09-2018
```

I am trying to split and store them into a string array, which is an instance of my object class:

```
 private List<ItemObjects> itemList;
```

and this is the constructor of my object class:

```
    public ItemObjects(String photo, String name, String link, String date) {
    this.photo = photo;
    this.name = name;
    this.link = link;
    this.date = date;
}
```

I tried this but the ":" separator doesnt separate it like I want it to:

```
                while ((sItems = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!sItems.equals("")) {
                    String[] tmpItemArr = sItems.split("\\:");

                    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects(tmpItemArr[0], tmpItemArr[1], tmpItemArr[2], tmpItemArr[3]));
                }
            }
```

What is the best way of doing this? I have tried using for loop which stops at third line and adds the next one as new data. There are several online ways of doing it but some are very complicated and I am having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your understanding of using both the split function and the BufferReader.
By using readline function you are reading only one line so your split will split the first line only, you need to read the 4 first lines then add the item.

```
  int count = 0;
  String[] tmpItemArr = new String[4];
  while ((sItems = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!sItems.equals("")) {
            tmpItemArr[count] = sItems.split(":")[1];
            count++;
            if (count > 3) {
                listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects(tmpItemArr[0], tmpItemArr[1], tmpItemArr[2], tmpItemArr[3]));
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So the logic is, the `sItems.split(":")[1];` reads whatever comes after the ":" separator? For the line in text file `Website: https://www.f.....` , wont it splits the ":" at the https as well?

Comment: split your entities using ";" is better